# Hardware Accelaration shows black Screenshots

Tags: animation, graphics, screenshot, takesscreenshot

What happens internally when Hardware Accelaration is **on** then all the screenshots taken during that time come out to be totally black.
I dont have any clue about that and have done some research but could not find anything.
I am trying to create an app 'X' in windows which will produce black screen as output when someone tries to take a screenshot while 'X' is on.
There are some apps which provide this functionality(like ScreenWings) but i could not figure out its working.
Is there any way hardware accelaration is related to this, if yes then how and if not then what can I use.
please help!!!

EDIT-- I want to do something so that screenshot comes out to be black..

Comment: I got a bit lost in your wording so just to be sure you want to have black screenshots or you want to avoid it and obtain the real image?

Comment: I am making a screen sharing app which will be installed in 2 PC's say A and B. A will share his screen with B so B can see the demo which A is giving on his screen. Now if B tries to record the screen(or screenshot) through some 3rd party apps(or PrtScn), then B will get a black screen as output of the recording software.

Comment: @Spektre           Basically what I want is to avoid my screen to be captured by B. B can only see the demo but cannot record/store it. If you have any idea to achieve this pls do tell..

Comment: No I do not know how but form what I know/remember/heard/read/saw if you are rendering using DX or OpenGL usually on Full Screen  then in some cases the frame buffer is not shared with Windows Desktop. I saw this behavior in some apps back in the days of W9x, XP and W2K.For example Media player was like this ... even some webcam video capture windows behaved like this... When I tried it now (W7) it looks like screenshots get the image now on... so there might be change in the architecture behind this, gfx drivers or god know what... Also it depends how are you obtaining the screenshot ...

Comment: However the first time I encounter this behavior was done by HW itself... By VooDoo 3Dfx as it generated videosignal on top of standard gfx layer by VGA cable bypass so OS had not any standard API capable of retrieving the rendered image. In case the DX/GL is not capable of this anymore than you can try to identify image recorders apps running instead...